# First for loop take much time

Tags: java, memory, operating-system, resources

Its second time I'm putting this question as the first time it's marked as a duplicate but I didn't get an answer this time I put certain modification in it.

Nowadays I'm working on optimization of code and I see a lot of code in which we create a new variable and then initialize as seen in the first loop in an example code below:[Code example](https://ideone.com/zVI6rx)

```
BigInteger limit = new BigInteger("10000");
long l = System.currentTimeMillis();
for (BigInteger i = BigInteger.ONE; i.compareTo(limit) < 0; i = 
i.add(BigInteger.ONE))
{
    BigDecimal temp = new BigDecimal(0);
}
long l1 = System.currentTimeMillis();

//After modification
BigDecimal temp1;
for (BigInteger i = BigInteger.ONE; i.compareTo(limit) < 0; i = 
i.add(BigInteger.ONE))
{
    temp1 = new BigDecimal(0);
}
long l2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
System.out.println("1st loop time: "+(l1-l)/1000.0);
System.out.println("2nd loop time: "+(l2-l1)/1000.0);
```

And then in second, I put some modification as shown. My question is both looks familiar, only variable scope is different but the first loop takes much time.

Ok as certain people said use modified code but then I made another experiment like this: [Code example](https://ideone.com/aKC7PT)

```
BigInteger limit = new BigInteger("10000");
long l = System.currentTimeMillis();
BigDecimal temp1;
for (BigInteger i = BigInteger.ONE; i.compareTo(limit) < 0; i = i.add(BigInteger.ONE))
{
    temp1 = new BigDecimal(0);
}
long l1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
for (BigInteger i = BigInteger.ONE; i.compareTo(limit) < 0; i = i.add(BigInteger.ONE))
{
    BigDecimal temp = new BigDecimal(0);
}
long l2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
System.out.println("1st loop time: "+(l1-l)/1000.0);
System.out.println("2nd loop time: "+(l2-l1)/1000.0);
```

In this first loop is taking much time as compared to the second But people said the first one is better or some said the second one is better but I don't think so. Provide some example so that I can understand which one is best and why it's happening so.

Comment: Better in what terms ? In performance, I think the first loop is better cause you do not  delete/create a new variable each loop. In terms of logic/safety, the second one is better, cause your temp variable is really temp and do not persist between loops (and outside of the for loop)

Comment: Ok as you said first one is better which one. If I move the first loop to second and second to first as shown the first one take much time. Is there any magic in JIT as every first loop take much time.

Comment: I did not said it is, I said I think it is. But it need to be verified, and moreover, proved that is is or it is not. But looking at your test result, and what you add in comment, I'd said your test is not giving exploitable results. The difference is too small to give info, and If the position of the loops changes the results, it means there is something else that happens, than just creating/deleting variable. The compiler might optimized some things.

Comment: If this is purely theoretical, for research, might be interesting to use a longer loop, and to compare bytecode, instead of code. If this is a need for a concrete project. You either don't care about such a small difference, and then better choose the logi/safe loop. Or if you care about this difference, you'd better choose another language than Java, that will allow you a better control on how to optimize the system usage

Comment: Yes, but I have to figure it out using java why it's happening so.

Answer (score 0):

If you are considering time complexity of the code
Then both loops have similar complexity and for memory complexity the declaring reference variable in loop might use 
More stack memory , also it could happen that compiler adds some optimisation in the code which can be the reason you see difference in time , you can also add volatile modifier on your method to check the actual performance .volatile will force compiler to not to do any optimisation on the method.